# Google sheets - Extract numbers with their units of measurment

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want a function that can extract numbers with their units of measurment from a text.

For example in A2 i have:

> This box weights 5kg and the other box weights 10 kg.

So i want a function that will return:

> 5kg 10kg

**NOTE: I want the function to work with any unit of measurment, not just "kg".**

I am a begginer in google sheets so it would be really helpful if you could provide me with a working function.

Comment: I suggest that you share a link to a sample spreadsheet with at least 20 rows containing a realistic range of data. Writing such a working formula around one isolated piece of data is almost impossible.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sample custom function that extracts words that starts with a number followed by a character/s.

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
function EXTRACTMEASUREMENT(input) {
  // match all words which starts with a number
  var result = input.match(/\d+[a-zA-Z]+\S*/g)
  // combine array into a string separated with spaces
  result = result.join(' ');
  // Remove special characters(except whitespace) in the string
  result = result.replace(/[^\/a-zA-Z0-9\s]/g, '')
  return result;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Limitations:**

- Measurements with spaces between the value and the unit cannot be detected. (See result in cell `A5` when space exist in `10 kg.`)
- Regardless whether the character/s after the number is a valid unit or not, it will be extracted. (See result in cell `A5` where `20yy` is not a valid measurement unit)
- If you want to exempt particular characters not to be removed, you can add them in the braces `[^\/a-zA-Z0-9\s]` (example `/` will not be removed).
  Note:

---

This can be improved if you can list valid measurement units that should be supported.

Comment: This script worked for me! But if i put in a cell "300km/h" it extracts "300kmh" without the "/". Can you update the script so that it supports that too?

Comment: I updated the answer to retain `/` in the result

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(
 REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "(\d+.\d+|\d+)", "×$1"), "×"), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, {"\d+.\d+ ","\d+.\d+","\d+ ","\d+"}&
 SORT({"nm";"mm";"cm";"dm";"km";"m";"t";"kg";"dg";"g";"l";"ml";"dl"}, 
  LEN({"nm";"mm";"cm";"dm";"km";"m";"t";"kg";"dg";"g";"l";"ml";"dl"}), 0))), 
 " ", ))),,9^9)), " "))
```

[image]

---

### update:

all in one cell:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(
 REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "(\d+.\d+|\d+)", "×$1"), "×"), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, {"\d+.\d+ ","\d+.\d+","\d+ ","\d+"}&
 SORT({"nm";"mm";"cm";"dm";"km";"m";"t";"kg";"dg";"g";"l";"ml";"dl"}, 
  LEN({"nm";"mm";"cm";"dm";"km";"m";"t";"kg";"dg";"g";"l";"ml";"dl"}), 0))), 
 " ", ))),,9^9))))
```

Comment: Can you edit this function but without the SPLIT? I want the numbers to be returned all in the same cell.

Comment: @BegCoder sure. answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=arrayformula(substitute(transpose(query(flatten(split(
REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([0-9.,/]+[ ]{0,1}[a-z1-3/.\-""]+)","♣♦$1♣")
,"♣")),"select * where Col1 like '♦%' ")),"♦",""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A:A),
  SPLIT(
   REGEXREPLACE(
    REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"("&
      REGEXREPLACE(
        REGEXREPLACE(
         REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"(\d+[.,/]*\d*(?:\w+|\s\w+)[\""./\-\w+]*)",""),
        "\s+\.","|\\."),
      "\s+","|")
    &")",""),
   "(\d)\s","$1")
 ," ",,1)
,))
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work! But it doesnt extract if the unit is for example: "30km/h" it only extracts 30km. How can this be fixed in the formula?

Comment: @BegCoder see edit.